# object-c and C# 3DES Encryption with different output

Tags: c#, objective-c, encryption

I have the following problem I would like to send my string encrqpted to my webservice and decrypt it there. But i got different output when I encrypt with object-c can somebody tell me what i'm doing wrong?

My encryption with object-c:

```
+ (NSString*)encryptData:(NSData*)inputData 
{
    NSData * key = [@"FeljWsN+uaEB9+jqDnPRQeIi" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    NSMutableData* outputData = [NSMutableData dataWithLength:(inputData.length + kCCBlockSize3DES)];

    size_t outLength;

    CCCryptorStatus result = CCCrypt(kCCEncrypt,                // CCOperation op
                                     kCCAlgorithm3DES,          // CCAlgorithm alg
                                     kCCOptionPKCS7Padding,     // CCOptions options
                                     key.bytes,                 // const void *key
                                     key.length,                // size_t keyLength
                                     nil,                       // const void *iv
                                     inputData.bytes,           // const void *dataIn
                                     inputData.length,          // size_t dataInLength
                                     outputData.mutableBytes,   // void *dataOut
                                     outputData.length,         // size_t dataOutAvailable
                                     &outLength);               // size_t *dataOutMoved

    if (result != kCCSuccess)
        return nil;

    [outputData setLength:outLength];
    NSString * outputString = [outputData base64EncodingWithLineLength:0];
    return outputString;
}
```

My encryption with C#:

```
public string Encrypt(string toEncrypt)
{
    string retValue = "";

    try
    {
        byte[] keyArray;
        byte[] toEncryptArray = UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(toEncrypt);

        keyArray = UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("FeljWsN+uaEB9+jqDnPRQeIi");

        TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider tdes = new TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider();
        tdes.Key = keyArray;
        tdes.Mode = CipherMode.ECB;
        tdes.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;

        ICryptoTransform cTransform = tdes.CreateEncryptor();
        byte[] resultArray = cTransform.TransformFinalBlock(toEncryptArray, 0, toEncryptArray.Length);

        retValue = Convert.ToBase64String(resultArray, 0, resultArray.Length);
    }
    catch 
    {
    }

    return retValue;
}
```

Object-c:

```
NSData * _secretData = [@"Christiaan" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSString * encryptedString = [TripleDES encryptData: _secretData];
```

gives me "Lp3x2fm2jrK1ftsHoZN9cg=="
and C#

```
Encryption encryptionSet = new Encryption();
string encryptedString = encryptionSet.Encrypt("Christiaan");
```

gives me "Lp3x2fm2jrJ7ghY9SXRlUw=="

Comment: Glad you've got it solved. You should either post your solution as an answer (if you think it will benefit other readers) or you should just delete the question. You should however never edit the answer into the question - the question will stay "unanswered" within the system.

Comment: I posted your answer in the answer section.

Comment: Oh Thanks! I'll remember that for the next time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

needed to add "| kCCOptionECBMode" behind the kCCOptionPKCS7Padding:

```
CCCryptorStatus result = CCCrypt(kCCEncrypt,                // CCOperation op
                                kCCAlgorithm3DES,           // CCAlgorithm alg
                                kCCOptionPKCS7Padding | kCCOptionECBMode, // CCOptions options
                                key.bytes,                 // const void *key
                                key.length,                // size_t keyLength
                                nil,                       // const void *iv
                                inputData.bytes,           // const void *dataIn
                                inputData.length,          // size_t dataInLength
                                outputData.mutableBytes,   // void *dataOut
                                outputData.length,         // size_t dataOutAvailable
                                &outLength);               // size_t *dataOutMoved
```

<sub>Note: this was extracted from the question and posted here on the OP's behalf.</sub>